# Issues with the JRE when attempting to open an AEM instance by using JDK 11.0.19 on Ubuntu

Tags: java, aem, java-11

I have installed JDK 11.0.19 on Ubuntu from Oracle, but I am encountering issues with the JRE when trying to open an Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) instance. AEM Forms does not support newer JDK versions, and I need to ensure compatibility by setting up a compatible JRE version.

Could someone provide guidance on how to configure the JRE to work with JDK 11.0.19 on Ubuntu for Adobe Experience Manager (AEM) Forms?

Comment: Adoptium still has [older versions of the jdk](https://adoptium.net/temurin/archive/?version=11).

Comment: `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`

Comment: @k314159 does that install the specific revision op is asking about?

Comment: JRE is not supporting while opening AEM Instance

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca no, it installs the latest Java 11 version, but the OP doesn't actually need 11.0.19 specifically. The version compatibility is detailed at https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/experience-manager-65/content/implementing/deploying/introduction/technical-requirements

Comment: @IshappaCodilar Ok, now your question is completely different. What do you mean "getting issue"? What configuration problem are you having.

Comment: `sudo apt install openjdk-11-jdk`    even I used this command It will Install JDK 11.0.22(JRE will work in this version), unfortunately this version is not get support to AEM forms.

Comment: Your actual question seems to be "how do I run a JAR in Ubuntu?", which is off-topic here on stackoverflow. Open a terminal, go to that directory and type `java -jar AEM-Cloud-author-p4502.jar`

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca In terminal it is working, why can't able to open directly by using jar file?

Comment: @IshappaCodilar again, that's an off-topic question here. Look for appropriate documentation on how to associate jar files to an appropriate jre in ubuntu. I don't know how to do that in ubuntu specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download it directly from Oracle's website: https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html